# Merging of input stream with a byte buffer

Tags: java, servlets, inputstream, java-io

I am trying to read multi part request body in my servlet.

I want to separate out the text params and the file params. Text params are sent in the beginning followed by the file params.

But i have to read the whole servlet input stream chunk by chunk in a byte buffer . I identify the start of the file param and stop there.

For e.g.

```
 Chunk1 = text param1
 Chunk2 = text param2 + file param
 Chunk3 = file param
 Chunk4 = file param
```

So, once i see the file param in chunk2 i will stop reading from the request stream. and then i want to merge the content of reminder of chunk2 and remaining chunks (i.e. still there in request stream ).

i.e remaining byte buffer of chunk2 and remaining in request stream

Is it possible to merge the byte buffer and the remaining of request stream.? I don't want to copy the stream into another stream as that would create a performance lag.

Best Regards,
Saurav

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're trying to do (code examples would help) but maybe `java.io.Sequence*Stream` combined with `java.io.ByteArray*Stream` is what you want?

Comment: awesome...thanks @Slaw...i was looking something like SequenceInputStream only